# PowerShell Active Directory search

Tags: powershell

I was tasked with developing a tool that Searches Active Directory to see all users within a group. Now it is a bit more complex than that. The tool needs prompt the user for input, based on that input it searches for a specific group matching the input. For example: I input T4 it pulls the T4Admin security group within the searched OU. This part I did without issue.

Now, where I am stuck is I need to search for users containing a certain string "_OUAdmin" then pull those out into a variable.

My code (excluding OU Path for security purposes):

```
#Prompts the user for OU Prefix and stores in the "ouPrefix" variable.
$searchPrefix = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter desired OU Prefix'

#Searches Active Directory for desired OU Prefix.
$selectedPrefix = Get-ADgroup -SearchBase "OU Path Cannot disclose" -Filter ('Name -like "*' + $searchPrefix + '*"')

#Pulls all group members from $selectedPrefix that contain "_OUAdmin". This is where I need help
#Help Needed Here!

#Removes "_OUAdmin" from all members.
#$modifiedAdmins =

#Appends "@test.com" to all members.
#$ouContacts =

#Displays Results of all OU Admin contacts in specified OU Prefix.
#Write-Host "OU Admins of '$searchPrefix' are $ouContacts"
```

I only need help in this one section called out "Help Needed Here!".

I am a beginner with PowerShell and therefore I am missing something probably simple, but any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us in what user attribute this  "_OUAdmin" string can be found and if it is just part of a possible longer string or not. Can you give examples?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible starting point for you:

```
$gm = @()

 ForEach ($member in $selectedPrefix) {
    $memberType = $member.objectClass
       If ($memberType -eq 'user' -and $member.SAMAccountName -like '*_OUAdmin*' ) {
            $gm += $member.name
            }
        }
```

The value of *$gm* should now equal each member of the groups that has OUAdmin their name in an array.

Comment: Thank you Ozymandius. So using this is not pulling all the users. Any idea why? I am at a roadblock as I am still trying to learn

Comment: How many is it returning and are they from specific groups? Are any of the groups nested? Finally, if you change *SAMAccountName* to *name* in the code I provided, does it help? If not, which part of the user account are you expecting the part value OUAdmin to exist in?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be:

```
$selectedPrefix | Get-ADGroupMember | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*_OUAdmin*"}
```

Or am I missing something obvious

Comment: Thank you Kulabtan, using this worked. However, now I can seem to figure out to assign this to a variable called $ouAdmins. It displays fine without a variable, but when saying: $ouAdmins = the line provided. My results do not show.

Comment: They won't show, as the stream gets "eaten" by the variable. To echo it to the command line do:
`$ouAdmins = $selectedPrefix | Get-ADGroupMember | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*_OUAdmin*"}`
and then:
`$ouAdmins`

Comment: So I need to figure out a way to store all the users in a variable then pass it to the next step. Ideally, no results will display until the end of the program.

Comment: Doing `$var = stuff` stores stuff in a variable. So $ouAdmins is storing the result of `$selectedPrefix | Get-ADGroupMember | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*_OUAdmin*"}`. You can just pass $ouAdmins to the next step of your process.

Comment: So I tried that then below I do Write-Host $ouAdmins and nothing displays?